# RefCell and Rc in rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a double linked list, but I have problems with the reference (Rc and RefCell. I try to use borrow_mut() for get the reference in a node, but it does not work, and the examples in internet is not enough for me. This is my code:

```
use std::{borrow::BorrowMut, cell::RefCell, fmt::Debug, ptr, rc::Rc, cell::Ref};

type Link<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T> 
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    rigth: Link<T>,
    left: Link<T>
}

impl<T: Ord + Debug> Node<T> {
    fn new(value: T, left: Link<T>, rigth: Link<T>) -> Self {
        Node {
            value: value,
            rigth: rigth,
            left: left
        }
    }

    fn insert_value(&mut self, value: T, prev_node: Link<T>) {
        if (self.rigth.is_none()){
            let mut new_node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value, prev_node, None))));
            self.rigth = new_node;
        }else {
            let mut aux: Link<T> = self.rigth.clone(); 
            match self.rigth.take() {
                Some(node) => {
                    node.borrow_mut().insert_value(value, node.clone());
                }
                None => {
                    println!("none");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Ord+Debug> List<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        List { head: None }
    }

    fn insert_value(&mut self, value: T) {
        if (self.head.is_none()){
            let mut new_node = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(value, None, None))));
            self.head = new_node;
        }else {
            let mut aux:Link<T> = self.head.clone(); 
            self.head.take().map(|node| {
                node.borrow_mut().insert_value(value, node.clone());
            }); 
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = List::new();
    list.insert_value(1);
}
```

This is the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `insert_value` found for mutable reference `&mut 

Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>` in the current scope
  --> .\double.rs:34:39
   |
34 |                     node.borrow_mut().insert_value(value, node.clone());
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&mut Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>`

error[E0599]: no method named `insert_value` found for mutable reference `&mut Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>` in the current scope
  --> .\double.rs:56:35
   |
56 |                 node.borrow_mut().insert_value(value, node.clone());
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&mut Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 3 warnings emitted
```

How I can use Rc and RefCell correctly for put multiple reference in rust? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: You need to first call `as_ref` and `unwrap` to get a reference to the `Rc` inside the `Option` before you can call `borrow_mut` to get a reference to the `Node`.